# Numpy def problem: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2

Tags: python, numpy

Can someone help me to fix this code to run monte Carlo simulations:

```
def utility_function(r_list, f_list,
                    y_list = np.array([1,0.5,0.25]),
                    xi_list = np.array([0.02,0.04])):
    U = y_list[0] + f_list[1] * (xi_list[0] - r_list[1])*(y_list[0] -y_list[1]) + f_list[2]*(y_list[0]*(xi_list[0] - r_list[2]) +y_list[1]*xi_list[2]+ y_list[3]*(r_list[2]  - xi_list[0]- xi_list[1]))

    return U
```

[Python output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHOWZ.png)

Comment: Please edit the full error message/traceback into your question as text.

Comment: Unless you know what's going to happen it's often a very bad idea to have default parameter values which are mutable because of unexpected side-effects. The value is only calculated once and if it's modified in the body of the function then the value is changed too for all subsequent calls.

Comment: A very simple debugging technique is to print each of those values used to calculate U - the one which causes an error will then become evident. Have you tried this?

Comment: Just to expand on @barny's comment, what you would do instead is have some immutable default value which would not be a valid input in its own right (typically `None`), and near the start of the code of the function, test if the parameter has this value, and if so, assign to it using the expression for the mutable object that you want to use (which will then create a new mutable object).

Comment: This is a simple case of out of bounds because it is...  `assert` the size of the arrays before you do the calc (or return -1 if bounds don't match requirements)

Comment: @RobRaymond The pythonic thing in that situation is probably to raise a `ValueError` (`assert` should be used for debugging rather than catching runtime errors)

Comment: `xi_list` has 2 elements.  It's complaining about the `xi_list[2]` term.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: first use `print(r_list, f_list, ...)` to see what you have in variables. Error means you have list without element `[2]`. Maybe if you see values you will know what is the problem. Probably you run `utility_function` with wrong list but problem is outside `utility_function`. OR maybe you use wrong indexes. OR maybe you should use `for`-loop to calculate it for lists with different sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of things you should correct, but the error is thrown due to this one:

- you have an default parameter `xi` that has 2 values but you are accessing the third (`xi[2]`) in your function.

Furthermore, you are accessing element 3 of `y_list`, which is only 3 elements long, so this will giv you the next error (`y_list[3]`).

Comment: @Prachi would you mind closing the question if it is solved? Thx